# Definite integral with the squared cosine under the square root

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, radicals

I can't solve this

$$\int_{0}^{5}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\cos(10 \pi x)\right)^2}dx}$$

My approach:
If $10\pi x =u \to 10\pi dx=du$, so $$\dfrac{1}{10\pi}\int_{0}^{50\pi}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\cos(u)\right)^2}dx}=\dfrac{1}{10\pi}\int_{0}^{50\pi}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{\pi^{2}}{8}(\cos(2u)+1)}dx}$$

And I don't know how continue this, and another thing is maybe elliptical integral...

Comment: Have you tried trig subs? 1+(tan x)^2 = (sec x)^2 might help.

Comment: But how??, you say change $\dfrac{\pi}{2}cos(10\pi x)$ by $tang(\theta)$..

Comment: Maple answers $$ 10\,{\frac {{\it EllipticE} \left( i/2\pi  \right) }{\pi }} .$$

Answer (score 1):

> *I can't solve this*.

No wonder you can't, since you are basically trying to evaluate the [arc length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) of the sine function, which is one of the main questions that gave birth historically to the notion of a special class of functions, called [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: Mmm Ok, but how can calculate this?? In wolfram, the result of integral is aprox, 7,318

Comment: @pabloperez: Are you asking for a *numerical* evaluation ?

Comment: Nop, I refer calculating the elliptic integral, because I know a little of this integral, greetings

Comment: @pabloperez: Are you not able to figure it out for yourself using the article I linked ?

Answer (score 0):

As Lucian is stating, the reason you cannot calculate this integral is because it so happens to be a type of elliptic integral. To put things in general, the elliptic integral is not one you can find the antiderivative in terms of "elementary functions", like polynomials, exponentials, sine, cosine, or even rational functions. Therefore, to evaluate it, we just "make up" an anti-derivative called "EllipticE(z)", as evaluated by Maple by user64494, or whatever you want to call it. These "artificial" anti-derivatives are constructed such that they do satisfy the fundamental theorem of calculus and all that you know about them. Another great example is evaluating $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{{-{x^2}}} dx$$. The solution to this integral is actually $\frac{\sqrt(\pi)}{2}$, but in order to get this answer, you would actually use what is known as the error function, which is $Erf(z)$, defined as

$Erf(t) = $$\frac{2}{\sqrt(\pi)}$$\int_{0}^{t} e^{{-{s^2}}} ds$

Of course, there are other ways of doing this, but if you go by just finding an anti-derivative as in Calculus I, then you would need to "construct" one, since there isn't one in terms of elementary functions. What is then left for you to do is either use numerical quadrature (evaluate using numerical methods), or in the case of this simple example, use polar coordinates. Note that if we take off the limits of integration off, then since we aren't evaluating the integral, then to find the antiderivative, we are left with no real choice but to go with the method I just highlighted. Thus, the general antiderivative would be:

$\frac{\sqrt(\pi)}{2}Erf(x)$ + C, where C is an arbitrary constant of integration.

Hope this helps to explain things somewhat.

Comment: Can't you find an antiderivative if you use Taylor series?

Comment: Yes, that is correct... I left that out in my initial post, thank you. (It's been a while since I've actually computed integrals.) But again, the point being is that if you want to find a closed-form expression for the anti-derivative, you will be resorting to "special functions" that are constructed solely for the purpose of evaluating said integral. The other techniques (polar coordinates, Taylor series expansion, etc...) may or may not help you in another problem like this. They are more specific to this problem.

Comment: BTW, your equation is misformatted. There should be a - sign in front of the x, not an underscore, in order to get sqrt(pi)/2.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, it should now be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{5}{\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2}\cos(10 \pi x)\right)^2}dx}=\left[\frac{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}E\left(10\pi x|\frac{\pi^2}{4+\pi^2}\right)}{20\pi}\right]_{0}^{5}=$$

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}E\left(10\pi*5|\frac{\pi^2}{4+\pi^2}\right)}{20\pi}\right)-\left(\frac{\sqrt{4+\pi^2}E\left(10\pi*0|\frac{\pi^2}{4+\pi^2}\right)}{20\pi}\right)=$$

$$\frac{5\sqrt{4+\pi^2}E\left(10\pi|\frac{\pi^2}{4+\pi^2}\right)}{20\pi}$$